# About Abstractive Text Summarization (Knowledge-based)

Tags: text, nlp, ontology, stanford-nlp, summarization

I am doing my 4th year project on **Abstractive Text Summarization**.

My task is to develop text-summarizer using *knowledge-based abstractive method*. I have done some research on this topic and I found some research papers too which consisted of only theoritical parts mostly and mentioned none about the implementation.

I have to complete this task in 2-3 months. Please suggest any good resources and some ideas for implementation of this project.

Comment: Did you succeed? What did you do?